# Symmetric shifted gaussian pulse

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, gaussian

Consider this short code:

```
fc=2e9;
fs = 100e9;
for n=1:2
  tc = gmonopuls('cutoff',fc);
  t{n}  = -2*tc:1/fs:2*tc;
  y{n} = gmonopuls(t{n}+n*5e-11,fc);
  fc=fc+5e3;
end
plot(t{1},y{1},'r',t{2},y{2},'k')
```

It generates a two *Gaussian mono-pulses* shifted by a slight amount:

[image: shifted gaussian pulse]

My problem is this: How do I make this symmetric? Note how the tails match up...they are zero for both the red and black pulse. I am new to the signal processing toolbox in matlab and want to modify the code below to have *matched heads* too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gmonopuls`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/gmonopuls.html) computes a Gaussian pulse which is centered at 0:

```
t = -2*tc:1/fs:2*tc;
y = gmonopuls(t,fc);
plot(t, y, 'k');
```

[image]

Evaluating this function at different time instants does not change the fundamental shape of the curve. It would only change which part of the curve you are sampling:

```
K = 2*tc;
for n=1:3
  t{n} = -2*tc:1/fs:2*tc + (n-2)*K;
  y{n} = gmonopuls(t{n},fc);
end
plot(t{1},y{1},'rx', t{2},y{2},'k', t{3},y{3},'bs');
legend('t-K','t','t+K');
```

[image]

To obtain a curve shifted along the time axis you simply need to add a time offset *after* you have computed your function:

```
for n=1:2
  tc = gmonopuls('cutoff',fc);
  t{n} = -2*tc:1/fs:2*tc;
  y{n} = gmonopuls(t{n},fc);
  t{n} = t{n} - n*5e-11;
  fc=fc+5e3;
end
plot(t{1},y{1},'r',t{2},y{2},'k')
```

[image]